# Shell Script not running properly on Git-Bash for Windows

Tags: git, mingw, git-bash, mingw-w64

I have git for windows 2.5.2 (64-bit version), downloaded from: https://git-scm.com/download/win

All I wanted was to create a .sh that would commit/push my work for me. I wrote the script and when I try to run it I get an error like:

"#!/bin/sh: No such file or directory"

As you can see I have my PATH set for my git-bash and my git-sh (also for my sh.exe and my bash.exe)

PATH-> "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\;"

I also have my ~/.bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

My ~/.profile:

```
#!/bin/sh.exe
#
# Get the aliases and functions
#

if [ -f ${HOME}/.bashrc ]
then
  . ${HOME}/.bashrc
fi

  export CVS_RSH="ssh"
  export EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
  export HISTSIZE="500"
  export PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```

And my simple script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh.exe

P_J="Le/Prjt/swks/games"
GITLAB_USER='myuser'
GITLAB_PASSWORD='mypass'
P_JG='G Select'
NAME_OF_REP='g-select'

cd $P_J || EXIT
cd "$P_JG" || EXIT
#git add -A
#git commit -m "$(date)"
#git push https://$GITLAB_USER:$GITLAB_PASSWORD@gitlab.com/$GITLAB_USER/$NAME_OF_REP.git
```

From my Git-Bash, here is an "echo $PATH":

```
$ echo $PATH /c/Users/UserP/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools:/bin:/mingw64:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

As I said, when opening git-bash and running my simple .sh I get this error:

./script.sh: line 1: #!/bin/sh.exe: No such file or directory

The problem seems to be when creating a variable on my shellscript. Does anyone have any idea of what may be causing this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand why it fails on line 1, but every one of your variable assignments looks malformed; in Bourne shell scripting, you __cannot__ insert arbitrary white space around the `=` operator. It __must__ be `VARNAME=VALUE`, whith no unquoted whitespace __anywhere__, (and _quoted_ whitespace only permitted __within__ `VALUE`).

Comment: I've never used the git-sh/git-bash fork of MSYS, but I do know that for MinGW.org's MSYS, we always caution __very strongly _against___ installing into any subdirectory of "Program Files", (or any other with whitespace in its absolute path name). See, that space is sure to turn around and bite you, eventually; I wonder is it doing just that, in this case?

Comment: Hey @Keith, thank you for your answer!

The spaces were, actually, a mistake of mine when copying the code here. My script didn't have that, so I edited my original post and removed those spaces.

Secondly, I tried to reinstall Git on a non-spaced folder (actually I did install it on C:) and, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

=(

Comment: @jthill: "_Yank the `.exe`_". Agreed, we don't normally specify `.exe` in the shebang, but with MSYS, from MinGW.org, on 32-bit Windows7, it makes no difference either way -- both `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/sh.exe` WJFFM. Maybe the git port, for 64-bit windows has broken this?

Comment: @MarceloPetrucelli, is your login shell properly initialized? How did you start it? What is the output from `type sh.exe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ./script.sh: line 1: #!/bin/sh.exe: No such file or directory

FWIW this error is usually caused by the abomination called the UTF8-BOM.

The character "Zero width no-break space" is used as a "Byte order mark" in UTF16. Several windows editors (notepad IIRC) also put this invisible (and useless) character at the start of a file encoded in UTF8.

If you have "Notepad++" the encoding menu item lets you choose between UTF8 and UTF8-BOM, switch the file to the former.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to run it? All I need to do at a command prompt is drag the file into the MINGW64 window so the file path and name appear, press enter, and it runs.

But if I preceed the file name in the command line with sh, I get that "#!/bin/sh.exe: No such file or directory" or similar that you mention.

That is:

$ [file path]

works.

$ sh [file path]

doesn't.